# How to remove test results during the ramping period from a CSV test result file?

Tags: awk

I have some test results in a CSV file. The first field has the timestamp, in milliseconds

Here is a sample record in the CSV file:

```
1628689875326,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
```

I want to remove the test results during the ramp-up (5 minutes from the start time) and the ramp down period (last 5 minutes) and write the filtered test results into a CSV file.

I tried with the hardcoded values

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

  BEGIN {
    endTime=1628689875326
    startTime=1628689875326-300*1000
    offset=1628689875326-3900*1000

    FS=","
    rowCount=0
  }
  {

    if ($1> startTime && $1<offset){
        rowCount++
        print $0
    }
  }
```

Comment: Presumably the timestamp is in microseconds, given your `*1000*1000` in your script. Does the answer have to use `awk`?

Comment: Sorry, the timestamp is in milliseconds.  Any solution with shell script or `Groovy` will be useful

Comment: If the time is in milliseconds your `300*1000*1000` does not equate to five minutes. 300 seconds (five minutes) in milliseconds is `300*1000`. Are you sure you don't mean that the timestamp is microseconds?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Hardcoded solution

In your hardcoded times script, this is the issue:

- `offset` is less than `startTime`, therefore the `if` condition

  ```
  $1> startTime && $1<offset
  ```

  can *never* be true.

The reasoning is that `startTime` is five minutes before the end (`5*60` = 300 seconds), but `offset` is 65 minutes before the end (`65*60` = 3900 seconds).

The solution is to change the initialisers to

```
    startTime=1628689875326-3900*1000*1000
    offset=1628689875326-300*1000*1000
```

---

This will set the relevant times as

```
endTime = 1628689875326
startTime = endTime - (3900*1000*1000) =  1624789875326
5 minutes before end = endTime - (300*1000*1000)  = 1628389875326
```

So, now, given a log file like this

```
1624789875326,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
1624789875327,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
1628389875325,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
1628389875326,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
1628389875327,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
1628689875326,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
```

Running

```
more test.log | ./filter.awk
```

gives the required result

```
1624789875327,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
1628389875325,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
```

---

#### A better solution - Getting the start time

However, examining your question further reveals that a few things are ill defined:

- Your `startTime`, in your script, is presumably the start of the filter, rather than the start of the actual log. The start of the log would be five minutes earlier, i.e.

  ```
  1624789875326 - 300*1000*1000 = 1624489875326
  ```
- You say that the time is in milliseconds, and yet you use `*1000*1000`, which implies *microseconds*.

Nevertheless here is a solution that will automatically find the start time (from the first line in the log file) and calculate the ramp time and therefore the start time of the filter.

It will also calculate the end of the filter time (in the same manner as your hardcoded script) - ***although you will still have to enter the end time***, i.e. the last timestamp in your log.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
  
  BEGIN {
    rampTimeMins=5
    rampTimeMillis=rampTimeMins*60*1000
    rampTimeMicros=rampTimeMins*60*1000*1000

    # Enter the start time
    # (not required, if NR conditional is used)
    startTime=0
    # Calculate Start filter time in microseconds 
    # (not required, if NR conditional is used)
    filterStartTime=startTime+rampTimeMicros

    # Enter the end time (required)
    endTime=1628689875326
    # Calculate End filter time in microseconds
    filterEndTime=endTime-rampTimeMicros

    FS=","
    rowCount=0
  }

  {
    if (NR==1){
      startTime=$1
      filterStartTime=startTime+rampTimeMicros
    }
    if ($1> filterStartTime && $1<filterEndTime){
      rowCount++
      print $0
    }
  }

  END {
    print rowCount
  }
```

**Note 1**: If your CSV has a first line which is a header, then change `NR==1` to `NR==2`

**Note 2**: If you want to use milliseconds instead of microseconds, just change `rampTimeMicros` to `rampTimeMillis`.

Here is an example log file, with an *additional* earlier time, which is the actual start time of the log (rather than the start time of the filter)

```
1624489875326,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
1624489875327,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
1624789875326,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
1624789875327,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
1628389875325,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
1628389875326,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
1628389875327,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
1628689875326,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
```

which running with

```
more test.log | ./filter.awk
```

gives the same result as before

```
1624789875327,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
1628389875325,327,3.1 HTTP Request /api/StaffPortal,200,OK,Concurrency Thread Group   SignIn-ThreadStarter 1-5,text,true,,73018,17,17
2
```

but with an additional row count.

---

#### Final solution - Getting the end time as well

If you change the line

```
    endTime=1628689875326
```

to

```
    "tail -1 test.log | cut -d, -f1" | getline endTime
```

Then the script needs no further editing as the last timestamp is obtained *before* the script runs. To make is generic use

```
    "tail -1 "ARGV[1]" | cut -d, -f1" | getline endTime
```

or better still (for safety's sake) pass a quoted file name to the spawned subshell, as per [Ed's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665995/how-to-remove-test-results-during-the-ramping-period-from-a-csv-test-result-file/666000?noredirect=1#comment1253637_666000):

> Change `"tail -1 "ARGV[1]"` to `"tail -1 \047"ARGV[1]"\047` so you aren't passing the file name to the spawned subshell unquoted (with all that would imply for globbing, word splitting, security, etc,)

where `\047` is a single quote (FWIW: `\042` is a double quote)), so:

```
"tail -1 \047"ARGV[1]"\047 | cut -d, -f1" | getline endTime
```

So the final script becomes

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
  
  BEGIN {
    rampTimeMins=5
    rampTimeMillis=rampTimeMins*60*1000
    rampTimeMicros=rampTimeMins*60*1000*1000

    # Enter the start time
    # (not required, if NR conditional is used)
    startTime=0
    # Calculate Start filter time in microseconds 
    # (not required, if NR conditional is used)
    filterStartTime=startTime+rampTimeMicros

    # Derive the end time
    "tail -1 \047"ARGV[1]"\047 | cut -d, -f1" | getline endTime
    # Calculate End filter time in microseconds
    filterEndTime=endTime-rampTimeMicros

    FS=","
    rowCount=0
  }

  {
    if (NR==1){
      startTime=$1
      filterStartTime=startTime+rampTimeMicros
    }
    if ($1> filterStartTime && $1<filterEndTime){
      rowCount++
      print $0
    }
  }

  END {
    print rowCount
  }
```

**Note 1**: If your CSV has a first line which is a header, then change `NR==1` to `NR==2`

Run the script (`filter.awk`) using

```
./filter.awk test.log
```

***not***

```
more test.log | ./filter.awk
```

---

**References**:

- This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22190928/4424636) to [cut or awk command to print first field of first row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22190902/4424636)
- This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12142006/4424636) to [How to detect the last line in awk before END](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12141938/4424636)
- This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1392999/4424636) to [how to cut columns of csv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1392990/4424636)
- [How to print filename with awk on Linux / Unix](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-print-filename-with-awk-on-linux-unix/)
- [7 different ways to print the last line of a file in Linux](https://www.theunixschool.com/2012/05/7-different-ways-to-print-last-line-of.html)
- [Awk](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#toc_Awk)

Comment: If you don't use a shebang to call awk, though, then you don't need to call awk to spawn a subshell to call tail, you can  just have shell call tail then awk, e.g. `awk -v endTime="$(tail -1 "$1" | cut -d, -f1)" 'script' "$1"`

Comment: @EdMorton - First comment: Many thanks, answer updated. Second comment: Fair enough, I understand your reasoning, but I wanted to give an awk-ish solution, without a shell (even though I ended up with a shell anyway, wrt the `tail`).

Comment: @JaneshKodikara Regarding "We need to ignore the first line as it contains the headers." - when you say "ignore", do you mean ignore it in the calculation and print it regardless, or not print it in the output at all? Whatever you mean you should add that requirement to your question and also show a few lines of sample input (including that header line) and the expected output.

Comment: @EdMorton - He seems to have printed the header to the filtered "results" file, in his answer.

Comment: Ah, yes I see that now, thanks. Hopefully they'll update the question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a shebang to call awk, use a shebang to invoke a shell and then call awk. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002754/1745001 for why.

I'd do what you want this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -F',' '
    NR==FNR {
        if (NR==2) {
            fiveMins = 5*60*1000*1000
            begTime  = $1 + fiveMins
        }
        endTime = $1 - fiveMins
        next
    }
    (FNR==1) || ( (begTime <= $1) && ($1 <= endTime) ) {
        print
        rowCount++
    }
    END {
        print rowCount+0 | "cat>&2"
    }
' "$1" "$1"
```

or you could get the timestamp from the last line by using `tail` (inspired by [@Greeonline's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/666000/133219)) instead of reading the file twice within awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v lastTime="$(tail -n 1 "$1" | cut -d',' -f1)" -F',' '
    NR==2 {
        fiveMins = 5*60*1000*1000
        begTime  = $1 + fiveMins
        endTime  = lastTime - fiveMins
    }
    (NR==1) || ( (begTime <= $1) && ($1 <= endTime) ) {
        print
        rowCount++
    }
    END {
        print rowCount+0 | "cat>&2"
    }
' "$1"
```

Either way you'd call it as:

```
scriptname input.csv > output.csv
```

or add the `> output.csv` after the awk script within the shell script if you don't mind hard-coding your output file name.

The above assumes your CSV has a header line that you want printed in the output.

Note how by not using a shebang to call awk I can use the shell to do what it does best, i.e. call other commands and use the script arguments multiple times, and just call awk to do what it does best, i.e. process text, leading to a more concise, robust, and efficient script than otherwise.

Comment: What does `' "$1" "$1"` at the end of the script do?

Comment: @JaneshKodikara - it runs the same input file twice, i.e. `awk -F',' 'blah' input.csv input.csv`. As this is now a shell script, `$1` is the first argument passed to the script, i.e. `input.csv`. This allows you to run this the script once to get the (`startTime` and) `endTime` value, and then run it *again* to do the actual filtering, with the start and end time values already derived. Hence the need for `NR==FNR`, to ignore the first section, when running the script for the second file. A neat solution.

Comment: Janesh - @Greenonline is correct. You have to get the `endTime` by reading the input file before parsing it to print lines with a timestamp less than the `endTime`. Greenonline called `tail | cut` to do that, I'm using `awk` to do it. The `tail | cut` is probably a little more efficient if your input file is large, it just wasn't the first thing that sprung to mind for me and either way the script will probably run in the blink of an eye anyway. Instead of manually specifying `$1` twice on the command line you could do `awk 'BEGIN{ARGV[ARGC++]=ARGV[1]} ...script...' "$1"`, whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Updated the given sample script with the following modifications.

1. Calculate the `filterStartTime` and `filterEndTime` based on the start time in the second row of the input file
2. Write the output into a file for further analysis

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
  BEGIN {
    testDurationMins=60
    rampTimeMins=5
    outputFileName="test-result-filtered-without-rampup.jtl"

    rampTimeMillis=rampTimeMins*60*1000

    # Enter the start time
    # (not required, if NR conditional is used)
    startTime=0
    # Calculate Start filter time in milliseconds
    # (not required, if NR conditional is used)
    filterStartTime=startTime+rampTimeMillis

    # Filter end time
    filterEndTime=0

    # Calculate the test duration  in milliseconds
    testDurationMillis=testDurationMins*60*1000

    FS=","
    rowCount=0
  }
  {

    if (NR==1){
      #Write header to the output file
      print > outputFileName
    }
    if (NR==2){
      #Set the filter start and end times
      startTime=$1
      filterStartTime=startTime+rampTimeMillis
      filterEndTime=filterStartTime+testDurationMillis
    }
    if (NR>2 && $1> filterStartTime && $1<filterEndTime){
      rowCount++
      print >> outputFileName
    }
  }
  END {
    print "" rowCount
  }
```

Comment: You're confusing awks semantics for `>` and `>>` with shells (you don't need `>>` in your awk script) and the `""` in `print "" rowCount` is doing nothing. If you had said in your question that you wanted to filter 60 mins of results instead of 5 mins less than the last time in the input, the answers you got would have been simpler.